# System.Type to XmlSchema built-in type

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am writing some class properties to an `XmlSchema` and at the moment I want to write the type in the `<xs:element type="xs:string">`.

Is there some mapping class so I don't have to write my own `switch-case`?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public void WriteProperty()
{
    // get the property that is a string
    PropertyInfo barProperty;
    XmlSchemaElement barElement;

    // I don't want this huge switch case for all basic properties.
    switch(barProperty.PropertyType.FullName)
    {
        case "System.String":
            barElement.SchemaTypeName = new QualifiedName("xs:string");
            break;
        // also for int, and bool, and long....


        default:
            //do other stuff with types that are not default types
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET framework does not have mapping classes or functions to do what you need.

I'd suggest to create a mapping dictionary instead than using a big switch:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> TypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
  { "System.String", "xs:string" },
  { "System.Int32", "xs:int" },
  . . . 
};

. . . 

  string schemaTypeName;
  if (TypeMap.TryGetValue(barProperty.PropertyType.FullName, out schemaTypeName)) {
    barElement.SchemaTypeName = new QualifiedName("xs:string");
  } else {
    //do other stuff with types that are not default types
  }
```

Comment: Odd that something that is built-in is not mapped buit-in.